# how to make Alexa correctly respond to: Alexa, ask (tell) [invocation name] (linking word if any) [intent Utterances]?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

When I say, "Alexa, open/launch/start Mighty Righty"
She responds as intended. When I say "Alexa, ASK mighty Righty who is right, me or you", she doesn't launch the app and just says: "Sorry, I don't know that one." I actually couldn't pass function validation for Amazon app certification because of that (I think). Here is the result of functional test:

1 Fix Required

The skill should not respond to intent requests with empty text or SSML in reprompt while keeping the skill session open.

The skill responds to users with an empty speech reprompt when the skill session is open. Please note that when the skill session is open, the skill should not return empty text or silent ssml response for any supported intent(s) within the skill.

Below are the list of intents that responded with a silent reprompt.

Intent Name - **playerBio**, Utterance - **who is right me or her**

Intent Name - **playerBio**, Utterance - **alexa ask mighty righty who is right me or my children**

Intent Name - **playerBio**, Utterance - **who is right me or you**

I have tried to play with LaunchRequest
IntentRequest
SessionEndedRequest
but I am not a coder. I just followed a tutorial and came this far. I just need to fix that error that Amazon "RUN" test found. And I will be able to publish the app.

```
#------------------------------Part1--------------------------------
# In this part we define a list that contains the player names, and 
# a dictionary with player biographies

Player_LIST = ["me or my wife", "me or my husband", "me or you"]

Player_BIOGRAPHY = {"me or my wife": ["She is. Do as she says, and you'll be OK.", "You", "Of course, your wife", "No doubt, it's you"],

"me or my husband": ["He is", "You are right", "He is not right", "Your husband. He is always right."],

"me or you": ["me", "You are, ... I mean... you are wrong, of course", "of course me", "It's me, don't you know that, my friend?", "you yourself, what do you think? Of course it's me", "I always know who is right, me or not me, so, it's meeeeee", "what do you think? I am Mighty Righty, so I am RIGHT"]}

#------------------------------Part2--------------------------------
# Here we define our Lambda function and configure what it does when 
# an event with a Launch, Intent and Session End Requests are sent. # The Lambda function responses to an event carrying a particular 
# Request are handled by functions such as on_launch(event) and 
# intent_scheme(event).

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event['session']['new']:
        on_start()
    if event['request']['type'] == "LaunchRequest":
        return on_launch(event)
    elif event['request']['type'] == "IntentRequest":
        return intent_scheme(event)
    elif event['request']['type'] == "SessionEndedRequest":
        return on_end()

#------------------------------Part3--------------------------------
# Here we define the Request handler functions

def on_start():
    print("Session Started.")

def on_launch(event):
    onlunch_MSG = "Hi, start with the word. Me. For example: who is right, me or my husband?"
    reprompt_MSG = "you can say, who is right, me or my wife?"
    card_TEXT = "Who is right, me or... ?."
    card_TITLE = "Choose your question."
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(onlunch_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)

def on_end():
    print("Session Ended.")

#-----------------------------Part3.1-------------------------------
# The intent_scheme(event) function handles the Intent Request. 
# Since we have a few different intents in our skill, we need to 
# configure what this function will do upon receiving a particular 
# intent. This can be done by introducing the functions which handle 
# each of the intents.

def intent_scheme(event):

    intent_name = event['request']['intent']['name']

    if intent_name == "playerBio":
        return player_bio(event)        
    elif intent_name in ["AMAZON.NoIntent", "AMAZON.StopIntent", "AMAZON.CancelIntent"]:
        return stop_the_skill(event)
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.HelpIntent":
        return assistance(event)
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.FallbackIntent":
        return fallback_call(event)

#---------------------------Part3.1.1-------------------------------
# Here we define the intent handler functions

import random # this can be at the top of the file too
def player_bio(event):
    name=event['request']['intent']['slots']['player']['value']
    player_list_lower=[w.lower() for w in Player_LIST]
    if name.lower() in player_list_lower:
        reprompt_MSG = ""
        card_TEXT = "You've picked " + name.lower()
        card_TITLE = "You've picked " + name.lower()
        return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(random.choice(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()]), card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)
    else:
        wrongname_MSG = "Some questions may not yet be present in my database. Try to rephrase your sentence."
        reprompt_MSG = "For example, who is right, me or my wife?"
        card_TEXT = "Use the full question."
        card_TITLE = "Wrong question."
        return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(wrongname_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)

def stop_the_skill(event):
    stop_MSG = "Bye for now and feel free to ask mighty righty who is right"
    reprompt_MSG = ""
    card_TEXT = "Bye."
    card_TITLE = "Bye Bye."
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(stop_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, True)

def assistance(event):
    assistance_MSG = "start with the word. Me."
    reprompt_MSG = "For example, who is right me or him"
    card_TEXT = "You've asked for help."
    card_TITLE = "Help"
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(assistance_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)

def fallback_call(event):
    fallback_MSG = "Try to say, for example, who is right, me or him?"
    reprompt_MSG = "Certain answers may not yet be in my database. Use personal pronouns, for example: me, or her, me, or him, me, or them. They can cover pretty much everybody"
    card_TEXT = "You've asked a wrong question."
    card_TITLE = "Wrong question."
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(fallback_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)

#------------------------------Part4--------------------------------
# The response of our Lambda function should be in a json format. 
# That is why in this part of the code we define the functions which 
# will build the response in the requested format. These functions
# are used by both the intent handlers and the request handlers to 
# build the output.

def plain_text_builder(text_body):
    text_dict = {}
    text_dict['type'] = 'PlainText'
    text_dict['text'] = text_body
    return text_dict

def reprompt_builder(repr_text):
    reprompt_dict = {}
    reprompt_dict['outputSpeech'] = plain_text_builder(repr_text)
    return reprompt_dict

def card_builder(c_text, c_title):
    card_dict = {}
    card_dict['type'] = "Simple"
    card_dict['title'] = c_title
    card_dict['content'] = c_text
    return card_dict    

def response_field_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(outputSpeach_text, card_text, card_title, reprompt_text, value):
    speech_dict = {}
    speech_dict['outputSpeech'] = plain_text_builder(outputSpeach_text)
    speech_dict['card'] = card_builder(card_text, card_title)
    speech_dict['reprompt'] = reprompt_builder(reprompt_text)
    speech_dict['shouldEndSession'] = value
    return speech_dict

def output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(outputSpeach_text, card_text, card_title, reprompt_text, value):
    response_dict = {}
    response_dict['version'] = '1.0'
    response_dict['response'] = response_field_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(outputSpeach_text, card_text, card_title, reprompt_text, value)
    return response_dict
```

I expect that error message "1 Fixed Required" to disappear. I will be able to submit my app to Amazon. Please, help me to publish my app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is clear and shows in the code. You have empty reprompts which is not allowed. You need to put a reprompt text in all places where you have `reprompt_MSG = ""`

Comment: I think it's another another question that I have to open to ask how to make Alexa react to: Alexa, ask Mighty Righty who is right, me or my wife? Instead of a lengthy process: Alexa, open Mighty Righty. (welcome msg here) Who is right, me or my wife? So my question is: Can you answer it here or I need to open another question on this website? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi. The fact that the functional tests pass has nothng to do with some aspects that will be caught by the certification team (humans) and they will reject the skill and send you the feedback you got about the empty reprompt. Functional tests run automatically. Certification tests are done by humans. This might help you: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/61d4a6ff-ed80-475a-b95e-d927989bc1de/tips-for-successful-alexa-skill-certification Please create another question with the other topc and I'll send you an example

Comment: Thank you German for your advice. I have created another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403361/alexa-open-mighty-righty-works-alexa-ask-mighty-righty-who-is-right